# PHP - Como fazer um GET puxar um include?

Tags: php

Se eu acessar uma página como por exemplo http://localhost/?cor=azul

> Utilizando o seguinte GET:

```
<?php echo  ($_GET["cor"]) ; ?>
```

Será imprimido o nome **Azul**.

É possível fazer com que ao invés de aparecer o nome "**Azul**", seja puxado um **include**?

---

Exemplo: Se a pessoa digitar: http://localhost/?cor=Verde

> Ao invés de ser imprimido só a palavra "**Verde**", será imprimido uma `<div>` que está dentro arquivo que foi puxado para o include, *exemplo (verde.php)*:

```
<div>A cor selecionada foi <b>verde</b> </div>
```

A pergunta é simples, é possível fazer um GET puxar um include?

Answer (score 5):

Sim é possível, nos meus projetos eu utilizo assim:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
if (file_exists($page.".php")) {
    include($page.".php");
} else if (file_exists($path_paginas . "/".$page.".html")) {
    echo stripslashes(file_get_contents($path_paginas . "/".$page.".html"));
} else {
    include("principal.php");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, só que você deve tomar cuidado, esse método não é recomendado pela comunidade.

Você pode fazer do seguinte modo:

```
function view($params = array()){
    /**
    * @params[0] retorna nome do arquivo
    * @params[1] retorna extensão do arquivo
    */

    if(file_exists($params[0].$params[1])){
        require_once($params[0].$params[1]);
    }else{
        require_once("404.php");
    }
}

view( array( $_GET["arquivo"], ".html" ) ); //executa função
```

Seguindo esse modelo de exemplo, você pode criar algo um pouco mais completinho. Hoje em dia existes vários métodos padronizados para se trabalhar com esse tipo de sistema, mas como é para conhecimento, siga-o.

Comment: O principal problema do seu método, é que o arquivo incluído estará dentro do escopo da função, e todas variáveis globais que precisem ser utilizadas terão que ser declaradas como global, em termos de segurança o meu também faz a verificação se o arquivo existe antes de dar o include, mas se quiser algo mais robusto, basta criar um array com todas as opções permitidas, mas pessoalmente acho desnecessário, já que o fileexists não confirma arquivos remotos...

Comment: Sim. Isso é verdadeiro.  Porém em geral o problema mesmo está no fato dele querer fazer assim. Como ele não explicou para o que queria, fiz esse exemplo à mostra.